# How to update webpage with contents of word document?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I am working on an application in VB.NET and I have created a ~90 page user guide for this application.

I would like to be able to link to parts of the document in my webpage.  For example, on the User's page I would like to provide a link to the section of the help document that contains the information about the User's page.

Is there a way that I can use VB.NET to extract information from my Word document and insert it on the the User's Page help link?

I have found some information on Word Automation but I am unsure if this is what I want, as I believe Word Automation creates the word document instead of extracting information from a word document.

Any help would be greatly appreciate!

Clarification:  I have a document that I want to load information from into different web pages.  I am trying to avoid having to update the document and update the various pages containing information from the document.  Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Comment: So you want a web page to open a word document on a certain page, depending on which web page link is clicked?

Comment: I want to use StreamReader or something like it to find a specific section of the document and then update that section of the website with the information from the document.

Comment: Are you sure there is no other way? Ideally, you have a help management application, which has its own format, and can generate word, html, CHM etc., all of which are up-to-date. You typically should avoid the need to parse a Word document, there could be many potential issues with this approach.

Comment: I'm sure there are other ways, I'm just trying to avoid having to make changes in two places.  I want to be able to update in one place and have those changes reflected in another place essentially.  I just can't think of any other way.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What I just said - you should have a central place for documentation, but this central place cannot be a Word document. It's like having an up-to-date copy on paper and then having to rescan it, OCR and upload to FTP to update the web version. You will need some research prior to selecting an approach. Two ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619254/what-is-the-latest-documentation-tool and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665925/what-are-some-good-net-code-documentation-tools.

Comment: I'm unfortunately unable to use external tools as they haven't been approved.

Comment: My suggestion: what you learnt here so far - communicate that to the decision making team in your company. I have no financial or any other interest in this recommendation. There is a chance some 3rd party tool will eventually be approved, eliminating the need for this work. From a developer's standpoint, you don't want to be the person maintaining a Word -> HTML sync, so fight your way against it.